# Cops and robbers program to find the most frequent character in a string

Tags: java, strings

I made this program to train me for a competition. The hypothetical question I've used was

> The cops need help finding who is the most probable criminal to commit a crime.
>   Witnesses tell them multiple different people, making it hard to find the criminal.
>   Use your knowledge of coding and the one-letter identifications provided for the criminals
>   to find who most likely did it and print.

It was fun making the code; however, it felt like it took too long for such a simple code. Is there any way to make this simpler or better?

```
import java.util.*;

public class CopsAndRobbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //The cops need help finding who is the most probable criminal to commit a crime
        //Witnesses tell them multiple different people, making it hard to find the criminal
        //Use your knowledge of coding and the one-letter identifications provided for the criminals
        //To find who most likely did it and print.

        TreeSet<String> done = new TreeSet<String>();
        ArrayList<String> all = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Integer> num = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<String> some = new ArrayList<String>();
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = sc.nextLine();

        for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
        {
            done.add(String.valueOf(input.charAt(i)));
            all.add(String.valueOf(input.charAt(i)));
        }
        int amount = done.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
        {
            String letter = done.first();
            int tempNum = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j < all.size(); j++)
            {
                if(all.get(j).equals(letter))
                {
                    tempNum++;
                }
            }
            num.add(tempNum);
            some.add(letter);
            done.remove(letter);
        }
        int highest = 0;
        int overallIndex = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < num.size(); i++)
        {
            if(num.get(i) > highest)
            {
                highest = num.get(i);
                overallIndex = i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The most likely criminal is " + some.get(overallIndex) + " with " + highest + " witnesses.");
    }

}
```

Sample Input

```
aggdhaamfa
```

Sample Output

```
The most likely criminal is a with 4 witnesses.
```

Comment: You also need to know that it is very difficult to dry run and reverse engineer the logic of someone else's code. If you want our help then please enhance the problem description with sample input and output, logic description, edge cases, etc.  Then, describe your solution and add description to the variables or better names

Comment: How long is 'too long'?

Comment: @h.j.k. anything shorter or quicker to type is not "too long" i guess

Comment: Are you referring to the runtime performance of your 'simple code'? Did you only test with your sample input, or did you attempt to use a 1000-character `String`?

Comment: @h.j.k with this code, runtime performance is not much of a problem for me; it can run in the background without needing to be touched; however, the time it takes to write is the issue; a quicker method of creating such program is my goal.

Comment: Ah in that case I'll remove the `performance` tag. I've illustrated *two* shorter approaches in my answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `try-with-resources`

Since Java 7, you can use [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) on your `Scanner` for safe and efficient handling of the underlying I/O  resource.

```
// Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
// ...
// scanner.close();
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    // ...
}
```

#### Interfaces over implementations, and generic type inference

Declarations should be done as `List` instead of `ArrayList`, and since *Java 7*, you are able to rely on [generic type inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) for simplification too:

```
// ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

#### Index-based retrieval across different `List` instances

Your usage of the `num` and `some` lists are merely the keys and values to what should be modeled as a `Map`, i.e. the number of occurrences to the 'smallest'

#### Problem formulation (and unit testing)

What will be the expected solution if there is an equal number of witnesses for two suspects? Or when there are no witnesses?

From your implementation, it suggests that it will pinpoint the 'smallest' character for the former, and will simply crash with an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` at `some.get(overallIndex)` for the latter, since `some` will be empty and `overallIndex` is initialized to `0`.

This suggests that you should be writing a *unit test* for your implementation too (after putting the logic in its own method), to make sure your expectations are *verified*. On a related note, even your sample output is *wrong*, there's only `4` occurrences of `a` in `aggdhaamfa`.

#### Stream-based approach

Putting it altogether, the whole logic can be quite easily done in one `return` statement:

```
private static Map<Character, Integer> maxOccurrence(String input) {
    return Stream.of(Objects.toString(input, "").chars()
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    i -> (char) i.intValue(),
                    Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    Entry::getValue,
                    TreeMap::new,
                    Collectors.mapping(
                            Entry::getKey,
                            Collectors.reducing('~',
                                    (a, b) -> a.compareTo(b) < 0 ? a : b))))
            .lastEntry())
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Entry::getValue,
                    entry -> entry.getKey().intValue()));
}
```

For starters, we deal with `null` input safely via [`Objects.toString(Object, String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#toString-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-), before we stream on its characters via [`String.chars()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#chars--).

Then, the first [`Collectors.groupingBy(Function, Collector)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) gives us our preliminary result, [`counting()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#counting--) each character's presence.

Next, we need to then group by their occurrence, so the second [`Collectors.groupingBy(Function, Supplier, Collector)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-) is used in conjunction with a `TreeMap` so that we can get our highest repeated character(s) as the [`lastEntry()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#lastEntry--).

The character(s) are checked against each other using [`Collectors.reducing(T, BinaryOperator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#reducing-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) to find out which is the 'smallest', using `~` as an initial value as it is an arbitrary large character compared to the standard English alphabet.

Finally, since `lastEntry()` can potentially give us a `null` for an empty `Map`, we wrap it up in a `Stream` just so we can [filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) `null` away, before finally converting the `Entry` representation into a `Map` via [`Collectors.toMap(Function, Function)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-). This will return an empty `Map` at the very least.

#### Plain-old iteration

Of course, if the above approach looks too... *advanced*, the plain-old iteration approach is even simpler and easier to comprehend (with only a tiny bit of Java 8/9 magic):

```
private static Map<Character, Integer> maxOccurrence(String input) {
    Map<Character, Integer> occurrences = new HashMap<>();
    int maxCount = 0;
    char mostRepeated = '~';
    for (char c : Objects.toString(input, "").toCharArray()) {
        if (occurrences.merge(c, 1, Integer::sum) > maxCount
                && c < mostRepeated) {
            maxCount = occurrences.get(c);
            mostRepeated = c;
        }
    }
    return maxCount == 0
            ? Collections.emptyMap()
            : Map.of(mostRepeated, occurrences.get(mostRepeated));
}
```

Here, we update our `occurrences` map by [`Map.merge(K, V, BiFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) and compare against `maxCount`/`mostRepeated` sequentially. The use of `Collections.emptyMap()` and [`Map.of(K, V)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#of-K-V-) is slightly better too, as they ensure the results are immutable.

Comment: I haven't really thought about using maps; thanks for suggesting it. I'll learn how to use those to make it similar. Thank you for the great insight.

Comment: Quick question: is it unsafe to not use try-with-resources on a scanner, or is that just a sort of insurance policy?

Comment: Sort of an insurance policy. :) If you do use it, make sure the `Scanner` instance is only closed once in the `main()` method, when the program exits.

Comment: I was told that the scanner instance did not need to be closed in most cases; should I still close it when I'm done with it?

Comment: Generally, it's a good practice that I/O resources be closed when you no longer require access to them, this helps the JVM and presumably the OS. Before Java 7, you might have come across older boilerplate code that does this explicitly, which has improved considerably since then. While there's nothing wrong with not closing a single `Scanner` instance inside the `main()` method since it will be closed when the method completes and the application ends, you should not rely on the same thinking once you start dealing with a multitude of opened files or network connections in a larger codebase.

Answer (score 4):

```
for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
{
    done.add(String.valueOf(input.charAt(i)));
    all.add(String.valueOf(input.charAt(i)));
}
```

Instead of iterating over the input string like that, converting every single character to a new `String`, actually doing all of this twice, and adding each to a collection, you can convert the string to a list of `String`s (for each character) like this:

```
List<String> inputChars = Arrays.asList(input.split(""));
```

Note that previously to Java 8 this results in the first element being an empty string, which must be handled accordingly.

Then add all of the characters in the array to the collections:

```
done.addAll(inputChars);
all.addAll(inputChars);
```

---

```
int highest = 0;
int overallIndex = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < num.size(); i++)
{
    if(num.get(i) > highest)
    {
        highest = num.get(i);
        overallIndex = i;
    }
}
```

To better structure your code, move the loop to a method `findIndexOfHighest()`. Your `overallIndex` actually is the `indexOfHighest`. Then you get the index of the highest element and the highest element like this:

```
int indexOfHighest = findIndexOfHighest();
int highest = num.get(indexOfHighest);
```

---

Add blank lines between blocks of code, e. g. between for loops. That makes your code much more readible.

---

```
int amount = done.size();
for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
{
    String letter = done.first();
    int tempNum = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < all.size(); j++)
    {
        if(all.get(j).equals(letter))
        {
            tempNum++;
        }
    }
    num.add(tempNum);
    some.add(letter);
    done.remove(letter);
}
```

Here the inner loop can be a for-each loop. Also it should be in a separate method, because what it does is `countOccurences(String s, char c)`. The variable `tempNum` should be called `count` or `occurences`.

Comment: `List<String> inputChars = Arrays.asList(input.toCharArray());` does not compile.

Comment: @D.Everhard while these tips are very helpful and good practice that I should learn, I found h.j.k's answers to be a little bit more useful.